# AWS Datapipline - error in creating defination

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to create a data pipeline to redshift using AWS Datapipeline.
I tried to import a definition.

```
{
  "objects":[
  {"id" : "first",
  "type" : "SqlActivity",
  "database" : {"ref":"RedshiftDatabase"},
  "clusterId" : "",
  "username" : "",
  "password" : "",
  "databaseName" : "",
  "script" : "unload ('select _id from device_id_match LIMIT 100') to 's3://my_bucket' credentials 
                'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key=' delimiter as ',' ",
  "schedule" : { "ref": "Hour" },
  "startAt": "FIRST_ACTIVATION_DATE_TIME",
  "period": "1 hours",
  "occurrences": "3",
  "queue" : "priority"}]
}
```

But got the following error-

[image]

I am unable to resolve the error.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, as @Junren said the 'name' field is missing. This seems to be a very old version of pipeline definition export. Normally database is defined as a standalone resource, rather than inside the SqlActivity block.

Why don't you just use the Architect (data pipeline web UI) to build a pipeline from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

try to add "name" field to SqlActivity object. It should unblock you from this error.